# TikZ in (sub)section title

Tags: tikz-pgf, sections-paragraphs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to add a tikz/pgf command to section command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23830/how-to-add-a-tikz-pgf-command-to-section-command)

I would like to add a `tikzpicture` to a section title using:

```
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
\node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=1pt] (char) {#1};}}
```

and include it in a section:

```
\section{\circled{A}: Tool 1}
```

However, the following error message pops up:

```
! Use of \tikz@picture doesn't match its definition.
\pgfutil@ifnch ...ved@c \pgfutil@reserved@a \else 
                                                  \let \pgfutil@reserved@c \...
```

Using `\protect` did not do the trick.