# How do I put a note into the right margin, regardless of whether it's an even or odd page?

Tags: double-sided, marginpar

Suppose I am writing a book in which some sections are especially important.  I would like those sections to be identified by a `*` after the page number in the table of contents.  How do I get it there?

I can get extra stuff into the table of contents by putting `\addtocontents` into my text at appropriate places.  So in this case I'd presumably write something like `\addtocontents{\protect\marginpar{*}}` in my text in appropriate places.

But that's not right, because `\marginpar` tries to put its contents into the outside margin.  I always want to put the `*` into the right margin, regardless of whether I'm on an even or odd page.

It seems like it should be extremely easy to do this, but I can't see how.  Suggestions?

Comment: Does this question help: [How to put a star or other symbol in sections that are special (difficult, optional, etc)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24171/how-to-put-a-star-or-other-symbol-in-sections-that-are-special-difficult-o)

Comment: It helps partly.  However, I don't really want to put the symbol along with the section number; I want to put it after the page number so that it sticks out into what would otherwise be the margin of the table of contents.

Also, ideally I would not want to have to decide as part of the section macro whether to use the special symbol; I'd like it to appear if and only if I invoke a particular macro at any time within the section body (which is part of why I'd like the symbol to appear at the end rather than the beginning of the table-of-contents line).

Answer (score 9):

Using `\marginpar` may not be the best way to do this, but it is in fact not too difficult to set up (assuming there aren't any other `\marginpar`s within the scope of the TOC, but then there wouldn't be any normally).

So what what needs doing? Basically when the `\marginpar` is encountered we have to prevent LaTeX from choosing the outside margin. Instead we have to make it do what it it does when the option `twoside` isn't choosen. And that is basically setting the switch `@mparswitch` to false before typesetting the TOC and to true afterwards (if `\marginpar`s within the document should switch margins. This could then look like this:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\MakeRobust\marginpar

\makeatletter
   \def\marginparright{\@mparswitchfalse}
   \def\marginparoutside{\@mparswitchtrue}
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\marginparright \tableofcontents \marginparoutside

\section{foo}
\lipsum[2]

\section[Important\marginpar{*}]{Important}
test \marginpar{outside?}
\lipsum[1]

\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\newpage} % generate a pagebreak in toc for testing

\section[Again Important\marginpar{*}]{Again Important on page 2 in TOC}
test \marginpar{outside?}
\newpage
\lipsum[1]\marginpar{outside?}
\end{document}
```

And the result (second page) would be:

[image]