# special numbering of distinguished sections

Tags: table-of-contents

I am wondering how I could change the numbering of some of my sections (not all!) in `toc`. More precisely, I would like to add a `\bullet` or something like that to the superscript of their numbers (eg `I.10$^\bullet$ <title>` instead of `I.10 <title>`) to let the students know that these sections are not so important, they do not have to read them.

Comment: Welcome. You don't need to sign your post. Your name appears automatically.

Comment: You do specify which section is important? It's not to be done automatically, I suppose?

Comment: Is this a duplicate of [How to put a star (or other symbol) in sections that are “special” (difficult, optional, etc)?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24171/how-to-put-a-star-or-other-symbol-in-sections-that-are-special-difficult-o/24173#24173)?

Answer (score 2):

A quick trial solution, by definition of a `\notthatimportantsection` command which will add a `\unimportantindicator` to the toc, currently defined as `\bullet`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}%

\let\LaTeXStandardSection\section

\newcommand{\unimportantindicator}{\ensuremath{^{\bullet}}}


\makeatletter

\newcommand{\notthatimportantsection@@noopt}[1]{%
  \notthatimportantsection@@opt[#1]{#1}%
}%


\newcommand{\notthatimportantsection@@opt}[2][]{%
  \let\oldthesection\thesection%
  \begingroup%
  \renewcommand{\addcontentsline}[3]{}%
  \LaTeXStandardSection[]{#2}%
  \endgroup%
  \begingroup%
  \renewcommand{\thesection}{\oldthesection\unimportantindicator}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\numberline{\thesection~#1}}%
  \endgroup%
}%

\newcommand{\notthatimportantsection}{%
  \@ifnextchar[{\notthatimportantsection@@opt}{\notthatimportantsection@@noopt}
}%

\makeatother


\usepackage{blindtext}


\begin{document}


\tableofcontents



\section{Important}

\blindtext

\notthatimportantsection[Unimportant]{This is not really important}

\notthatimportantsection{Also not important}

\section{Important again}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: May be `\rlap{$^{\bullet}$}` and then using the default spacing rather than `\thesection~#1` (that `~` is not perfect there).

Comment: You should take a look at the `titlesec/titletoc` documentation, § 4.3 and 6.7. An environment and a marker  for `advanced sections` is defined, and how to enter them in the table of contents with their marker.

Comment: @Bernard: I will look later on... and think about a better solution, as I am not satisfied with this completely.