# Vertical space between a theorem environment and a customized section title is large

Tags: spacing, theorems, titlesec

I need to mark some section titles with asterisks to represent special sections. I adopted the method provided by [`titlesec` document](http://ctan.mirrors.hoobly.com/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.pdf) (sec. 6.7). Also, I found this topic had been discussed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24171/146373). Everything is ok except that the vertical space between a theorem environment (for me, it's always proof environment) and the asterisked section title is a bit larger than the space between two normal sections.

[image]

Here is MWE:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}


\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[amsmath,thmmarks]{ntheorem}
{
    \theoremstyle{nonumberplain}
    \theoremindent0em
    \theoremrightindent0em
    \theoremheaderfont{\bfseries}
    \theorembodyfont{\normalfont}
    \theoremsymbol{\ensuremath{\Box}}
    \newtheorem{proof}{Proof.}
}
% \usepackage{amsthm}
% \renewcommand\qedsymbol{\ensuremath{\Box}}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{subsection}}
\newcommand{\secmark}{}
\newcommand{\marktotoc}[1]{\renewcommand{\secmark}{#1}}
\newenvironment{advanced}{
    \renewcommand{\secmark}{*}
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\marktotoc{*}}
}{
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\marktotoc{}}
}
\titleformat{\subsection}
    {\bfseries\large}
    {\llap{\secmark}\thesubsection}
    {1em}
    {}
\newcommand{\starsec}[1]{\begin{advanced}\subsection{#1}\end{advanced}}
\titlecontents{section}[6em]
    {\bfseries\addvspace{1pc}}
    {\contentslabel[Chapter \thecontentslabel]{6em}}
    {Chapter }
    {\titlerule*{}\bfseries\contentspage}
\titlecontents{subsection}[3.7em]
    {}
    {\contentslabel[\llap{\secmark}\thecontentslabel]{2.3em}}
    {\hspace*{-2.3em}}
    {\titlerule*[10pt]{.}\contentspage}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{The first section}
\subsection{The first subsection}
    This is the first subsection.
    \begin{proof}
        Let's skip the proof.
    \end{proof}

\begin{advanced}
\subsection{The first asterisked subsection}
    This is the first asterisked subsection.

\subsection{The second asterisked subsection}
    This is the second asterisked subsection.
\end{advanced}

\subsection{Another subsection}
    This is another subsection.

\subsection{Normal subsection}
    This is normal.
\end{document}
```

The problem still exists if I use the proof environment provided by `amsthm` package. But when I remove `\addtocontents{toc}{...}` from the definition of `advanced` environment, the extra space disappears. So the problem must be concerned with `\addtocontents`. It seems that `\addtocontents` is a horizontal command? When a theorem encounters it, an extra space will be placed. The extra space is `\topsep` because `\theorempostskip{\topsep}` is default setting in `ntheorem`.

For me, `\addtocontents` is needed because I want table of contents to demonstrate whether a section is asterisked. Does anyone know how to eliminate the extra space and meanwhile have table of contents printed correctly?

Comment: The ‘whatsit’ introduced by `\addtocontents` is exactly the problem: the `\addvspace` command issued by `\subsection` cannot see the trailing `\addvspace` after `proof` as “immediately preceding”.

Comment: Do you need to do references to the subsection numbers?

Comment: The definition of `advanced` has some extra spaces produced by "unprotected" line endings.  Adding `%` at those places would be a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\addtocontents` makes impossible for the `\addvspace` command issued by `\subsection` to “see” the one issued by `\end{proof}`.

I propose a different approach:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=2.5cm,heightrounded]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\secmark\arabic{subsection}}
\newrobustcmd{\secmark}{}
\newenvironment{advanced}{%
  \renewcommand{\secmark}{\secasterisk}%
}{}
% normal behavior of \secasterisk is to print an asterisk
\newrobustcmd{\secasterisk}{*}
% in the toc and in section titles we want that the asterisk is 'llapp'ed
\newrobustcmd{\secasteriskzero}{\makebox[0pt][r]{*}}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@starttoc}
  {\begingroup}
  {\begingroup\let\secasterisk\secasteriskzero}
  {}{}
\makeatother

\titleformat{\subsection}
    {\bfseries\large\let\secasterisk\secasteriskzero}
    {\thesubsection}
    {1em}
    {}
\newcommand{\starsec}[1]{\begin{advanced}\subsection{#1}\end{advanced}}
\titlecontents{section}[6em]
    {\bfseries\addvspace{1pc}}
    {\contentslabel[Chapter \thecontentslabel]{6em}}
    {Chapter }
    {\titlerule*{}\bfseries\contentspage}
\titlecontents{subsection}[3.7em]
    {}
    {\contentslabel[\llap{\secmark}\thecontentslabel]{2.3em}}
    {\hspace*{-2.3em}}
    {\titlerule*[10pt]{.}\contentspage}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{The first section}

References \ref{testa} and \ref{testb}.

\subsection{The first subsection}\label{testa}
    This is the first subsection.
    \begin{proof}
        Let's skip the proof.
    \end{proof}

\subsection{Another subsection}
    This is a subsection to compare spaces.
    \begin{proof}
        Let's skip the proof.
    \end{proof}

\begin{advanced}
\subsection{The first asterisked subsection}\label{testb}
    This is the first asterisked subsection.

\subsection{The second asterisked subsection}
    This is the second asterisked subsection.
\end{advanced}

\subsection{Another subsection}
    This is another subsection.

\subsection{Normal subsection}
    This is normal.
\end{document}
```

[image]

I used `amsthm`. However, this doesn't mean you can't use `ntheorem` if you really prefer it. Anyway, I can't see why bracing `\newtheorem{proof}{Proof}` and the related settings.

Comment: Nice solution! Thanks! BTW, I braced them because I actually have different settings for other theorem environments and I just copied the part of proof environment into MWE.

Comment: One more question. I notice that the asterisk is part of label of asterisked subsections. When I reference an asterisked subsection, the asterisk appears. Can this be avoid? I hope to obtain only the number when referencing a subsection:)