# Undefined color error for URL, when compiling with XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, hyperref, color, urls

I've defined a different color for hyperlink using `\hypersetup` command with `urlcolor`. When I am compiling it with XeLaTeX I am getting `undefined color` error for the URL link, but it works fine when I compile with LaTeX (the color of the link changes). Similar error have been discussed before [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21954/undefined-color-error-if-have-symbol-in-chapter-title) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22768/how-to-use-beamer-colors-in-beamerarticle), but my problem seems to be a bit different. Below is a simplified example of code I am trying to compile:

```
\documentclass[10pt, a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\PassOptionsToPackage{pdftex,usenames,dvipsnames}{color}
\usepackage[bookmarks, colorlinks, breaklinks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue,filecolor=black,urlcolor=MidnightBlue} 
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\href{https://tex.stackexchange.com/}{https://tex.stackexchange.com/}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}` instead of the corresponding with `color`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would also receive a host of other errors. Here it is best to use

```
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
```

rather than "passing the options to the package". Since you're processing your file under `xelatex` anyway, I've dropped the driver support `pdftex`. By default I use [`xcolor`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor), although you could also use [`color`](http://ctan.org/pkg/color).

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt, a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[bookmarks, colorlinks, breaklinks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue,filecolor=black,urlcolor=MidnightBlue} 
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\href{http://tex.stackexchange.com/}{http://tex.stackexchange.com/}
\end{center}
\end{document}​
```